# Property of control is always null despite being set in code

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm clearly having a bad day because this one should be easy and I'm not seeing it. Ugh!

I've created a control derived from a `Panel` which will act as a container for some "Tiles" which themselves are a subclass also derived from `Panel`. So it's basically just multiple panels hosted in one big panel.
Each "Tile" has a `PictureBox` on it which will display an icon if set, and a placeholder if not.

All seems well except that despite passing an image into the Tile object when I create it the property is still null and the error icon is displayed.

Here's a cut-down version that you should be able to paste into a blank Winform. You'll need to provide your own image of course, I recommend you just grab one [HERE](http://dummyimage.com/60x60/000/fff).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Height = 500;
        Width = 500;

        MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();
        myPanel.BackColor = Color.White;
        myPanel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        myPanel.Height = Height - 50;
        myPanel.Width = 200;
        myPanel.Top = 5;
        myPanel.Left = 5;
        Controls.Add(myPanel);

        // I'M SETTING THE IMAGE AT CREATION, THE FILE IS DEFINITELY VALID
        MyPanel.Tile tile = new MyPanel.Tile();
        tile.TileIcon = Image.FromFile(@"path/to/file");
        tile.BackColor = Color.PowderBlue;
        myPanel.AddTile(tile);

        MyPanel.Tile tile2 = new MyPanel.Tile();
        tile2.TileIcon = Image.FromFile(@"path/to/file");
        tile2.BackColor = Color.PeachPuff;
        myPanel.AddTile(tile2);
    }    
}

class MyPanel : Panel
{
    private const int TILEHEIGHT = 75;
    private static List<Panel> tileIndex = new List<Panel>();

    public MyPanel() { }

    public void AddTile(Tile tile)
    {
        tile.Width = this.Width;
        tile.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
        tile.Top = tileIndex.Count * TILEHEIGHT;
        tileIndex.Add(tile);
        this.Controls.Add(tile);
    }

    public class Tile : Panel
    {
        // PROPERTY FOR IMAGE
        private Image _tileIcon;
        public Image TileIcon
        {
            get { return _tileIcon; }
            set { _tileIcon = value; }
        }

        public Tile()
        {
            base.Height = TILEHEIGHT;
            base.Left = 0;
            base.Top = 0;
            base.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF5555");

            // DISPLAY IMAGE IN PICTUREBOX
            // ALWAYS NULL!?
            PictureBox _picBox = new PictureBox();
            _picBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            if (_tileIcon != null)
            { _picBox.Image = _tileIcon; }
            else
            { _picBox.Image = Image.FromFile(@"path/to/file"); }

            _picBox.Left = 5;
            _picBox.Top = 5;
            _picBox.Height = (this.Height - 10);
            _picBox.Width = _picBox.Height;

            this.Controls.Add(_picBox);
        }
    }
}
```

**Wrong**
[image]

**Right**
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Because you are setting it in the constructor, `_tileIcon` is null, and when you set it on the property, it doesn't re-initialize the picture box. You need to set the `.Image` of the picturebox in the setter for the tile property. There is no point in setting picturebox to the `_tileIcon` in the constructor since the property will always be null.

Comment: Got it, cheers Ron. Knew it had to be simple. I'll go grab another coffee now... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it. I passed in an image to the constructor.

The problem, as I said in my comment is that in the constructor you haven't set the `_tileIcon` yet, so it will always be null. You set it after the constructor, but you don't reinitialize the picturebox to use that image. You need to reset the picturebox in the set for that to work.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Height = 500;
        Width = 500;

        MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();
        myPanel.BackColor = Color.White;
        myPanel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        myPanel.Height = Height - 50;
        myPanel.Width = 200;
        myPanel.Top = 5;
        myPanel.Left = 5;
        Controls.Add(myPanel);

        var icon1 = Image.FromFile(@"path/to/file");  //Load the image FIRST
        MyPanel.Tile tile = new MyPanel.Tile(icon1);  //Pass it into the constructor
        tile.BackColor = Color.PowderBlue;
        myPanel.AddTile(tile);

        var icon2 = Image.FromFile(@"path/to/file");  //Again, image first
        MyPanel.Tile tile2 = new MyPanel.Tile(icon2); //Then construct
        tile2.BackColor = Color.PeachPuff;
        myPanel.AddTile(tile2);
    }    
}

class MyPanel : Panel
{
    private const int TILEHEIGHT = 75;
    private static List<Panel> tileIndex = new List<Panel>();

    public MyPanel() { }

    public void AddTile(Tile tile)
    {
        tile.Width = this.Width;
        tile.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
        tile.Top = tileIndex.Count * TILEHEIGHT;
        tileIndex.Add(tile);
        this.Controls.Add(tile);
    }

    public class Tile : Panel
    {
        private PictureBox _picBox;

        // PROPERTY FOR IMAGE
        private Image _tileIcon;
        public Image TileIcon
        {
            get { return _tileIcon; }
            //Obviously needs additional logic for null images...
            set { _tileIcon = value; _picBox.Image = _tileIcon; }
        }

        public Tile(Image tileIcon = null)
        {
            _tileIcon = tileIcon;
            base.Height = TILEHEIGHT;
            base.Left = 0;
            base.Top = 0;
            base.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF5555");

            // Now this won't be null, and save a reference to the
            //_picBox so you can easily change the image later through
            //the icon property.
            _picBox = new PictureBox();
            _picBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            if (_tileIcon != null)
            { _picBox.Image = _tileIcon; }
            else
            { _picBox.Image = Image.FromFile(@"path/to/file"); }

            _picBox.Left = 5;
            _picBox.Top = 5;
            _picBox.Height = (this.Height - 10);
            _picBox.Width = _picBox.Height;

            this.Controls.Add(_picBox);
        }
    }
}
```